# Can I hold string variables in a string array? (Java)

Tags: java, android, arrays

Basic question here, can I put String variables into a position in a string array along with more text?

Here's what I'm trying to do

```
public static final String CAT_BUD_TAB = "CAT_BUD_TAB";
public static final String inI = "INSERT INTO ";
public static final String val = " VALUES ";

public static final String[] catInsertArray = new String[13];

catInsertArray[0] = inI + CAT_BUD_TAB + val + "(null, 'Student Loan', 'in', 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0, 0 );";
```

But obviously that's not going to work because it's expecting " to mark the start of the string to be contained. Is there anyway this will work?

**EDIT**

Nope its not the SQL im concerned with, I'm just trying to combine a bit of text with text from a string variable and hold them all as one long string in an array. Might have just made it more confusing, if so ignore this edit and just re-read the original question.

Got rid of the parenthesis as suggested and updated the code block above with all the relevant code.

**but eclipse is still saying there's a "syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens"** And has squiggly red lined the whole line of code (catInsertArray[0] = ....)

**pastebin of the class here if you'd be good enough to take a look http://pastebin.com/cKa0sKEj**

Comment: I'm confused, what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: Im confused, the code above is perfectly valid. Are you wondering if the actual SQL statement is valid?

Comment: Thanks the replies, but obviously im not being clear, edited original post above. user, you say the code is perfectly valid but alas i'm still getting a syntax error.

Comment: Please include a complete example that contains the syntax error.

Comment: I do get the token error, but to be able to pinpoint exactly what is wrong, can you show us the full class declaration and how you actually use this stuff? I suspect it's because you're actually trying to do the `catInsertArray[0]` stuff outside of any method body.

Comment: updated the code block uptop and the error again. Thanks all.

Comment: I'm going to be using it in an android application (not really relevant), but i will import the class and then i intended to do a for loop to initially fill my database table from this array like so db.execSQL(catInsertArray[i]);

Comment: @Holly, I posted an answer, which might tackle your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your original problem was having code that was outside of a method body. This demo class will compile and run, and has comments pointing out what you might have been doing vs. what would be correct.

```
public class StringTest 
{

    public static final String crT = "CREATE TABLE ";
    public static final String inI = "INSERT INTO ";
    public static final String val = " VALUES ";

    public static final String[] catInsertArray = new String[13];

    // you were probably doing this, which is not allowed in Java because you are writing code outside of a method body or static initializer block
    //catInsertArray[0] = inI + val + "(null, 'Student Loan', 'in', 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0, 0 );"; 

    static
    {
         // static initialize your static member
         catInsertArray[0] = inI + val + "(null, 'Student Loan', 'in', 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0, 0 );"; 
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        // You can put code in a method
        //catInsertArray[0] = inI + val + "(null, 'Student Loan', 'in', 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0, 0 );"; 

    }
}
```

From your new comment - the code you have in your pastebin link has a few issues. One thing I have is why you are declaring a nested interface inside your `DatabaseConstants` class? It seems unnecessary since you're making a class for constants.

Additionally, you still leave out a [`static` initializer block](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) to put things into your `String` array. See the code below.

```
package com.geistware.studentbudgetapp;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public class  DatabaseConstants {

    //Variables for DDL statements and such
    public static final String crT = "CREATE TABLE ";
    public static final String inI = "INSERT INTO ";
    public static final String val = " VALUES ";

    //Table Names
    public static final String CAT_BUD_TAB = "CAT_BUD_TAB";
    public static final String TWO_WEE_TAB = "TWO_WEE_TAB";

    //columns from the category_budget_table
    public static final String CAT_ITEM = "CAT_ITEM";
    public static final String IN_OUT = "IN_OUT";
    public static final String BUDGET_AMOUNT = "BUDGET_AMOUNT";
    public static final String ACTUAL_AMOUNT = "ACTUAL_AMOUNT";
    public static final String AMOUNT_STRAYED = "AMOUNT_STRAYED";
    public static final String OVERBUDGET_TF = "OVERBUDGET_TF";
    public static final String AUTOSPEND_TF = "AUTOSPEND_TF";

    //Initial DDL Statements and Initial INSERT statements to populate table
    public static final String createCATBUDTAB = (crT + CAT_BUD_TAB + 
            "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, CAT_ITEM TEXT, IN_OUT TEXT, BUDGET_AMOUNT REAL, ACTUAL_AMOUNT REAL, AMOUNT_STRAYED REAL, OVERBUDGET_TF INTEGER, AUTOSPEND_TF INTEGER);");
    public static final String createTWOWEETAB = (crT + TWO_WEE_TAB + 
            "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, SUB_CAT_ITEM TEXT, CAT_ITEM TEXT, COST REAL, ESSENTIAL_TF INTEGER, CURRENT_LAST TEXT, WEEK_ID INTEGER);");

    public static String[] catInsertArray = new String[13];

    // you still need to to put this code into a static initializer block
    static
    {
        catInsertArray[0] = inI + CAT_BUD_TAB + val + "(null, 'Student Loan', 'in', 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0, 0 );";
    }

}
```

However, for something like a list of constants, I'd prefer to use an [enumeration](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html), but hopefully this gets you on the right track to at least getting a working build.

Comment: I tried setting it up as you suggested and i think i'm still missing something as i still can't get it errorless, I've got a link to the pastebin of this class if you'd be kind enough to look at it and tell me how i should have it set up? http://pastebin.com/cKa0sKEj

Comment: actually upon further fiddling it seems that you're right, now my error messages are just about not being able to find the variables, and that makes perfect sense of course because they're not global! so stupid of me. Now i just need to work out my i need them in that interface method (followed a guide).. if you not why its necessary to have it that would be great, if not no worries, you've already answered my question!

Comment: @Holly, I do not think you need them wrapped in an interface, but I do not know the full context of the guide you're following. My edit strips down the code from your link above.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and helping me get to the root of my silly problem, everything's working great now :)

Answer (score 2):

If the value of the variables are also strings, you can do it. Remember that the array position is just a container.

But, you are not calling a method, so remove the parenthesis. Just do:

```
array[position] = stringVariable1 + stringVariable2 + " some other string";
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need the sperate parts of the SQL to be distinct?

You could just use a StringBuffer/StringBuilder to concatenate the bits you need, remembering to escape quotes as you go.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is nothing syntactically wrong
   with building the value for the
   array
2. There is a lot wrong "operationally" with what you are
   doing.

   - Your "CREATE TABLE", "INSERT INTO", etc. are not variables and should not constants.  Pulling the text into constants might reduce the total number characters used in the source    code, but it add much unneeded complexity.
   - Your SQL statements have hard coded parameters.  This is where a PreparedStatement might be much more useful.
   - Building an array by specifying the index looks a little scary.  Depending on what else you might be doing a List might make more sense.

Comment: Thanks for all the info, obviously i'm very new to all this, I've been doing a lot of learning new things and this is just my attempt at trying to apply things i'd learnt for a change. Looks like i might need to go back to googling.